# react-app-rewired build with GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false throws cannot find module

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, react-app-rewired

Title explains the most of it.
I have a react project using react-app-rewired.
On production build using GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false it fails to compile with the error:
`Cannot find module: '@rewiredlocation'. Make sure this package is installed.`

This is the build line in the package.json: `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-app-rewired build`

Are there any specific steps that I need to take upon building with react-app-rewired?